# What should be the response code when error is generated by third party application?

Tags: javascript, http, backend, convention

I built a web application that basically ask the user for credentials with a form (for a random 3rd party service, knowing which one does not matter).
Once the user filled the form with the 3rd party service app token, a request with the token is sent to the application backend, the backend gets the token and send a request to the 3rd party service in order to check if the token is valid. 
At this point the 3rd party service returns a response to the backend with either `200 - {randomObject: object}` or `401 - Unauthorized`.

So here is my question : If the 3rd party service returns 401, should the backend returns `200 - false` or `401 - Unauthorized` ?

Me and my colleague have been arguing about this. 
My point is that the access to the application backend is authorized and the parameters are correct (a token is present in the request), so the response should be 200 but the content of the response should indicate wether or not the token is valid.
His point is that since the token is not valid (as the 3rd party service tells the backend), the backend should return `401 - Unauthorized`.

Just so we're clear, I know that the outcome is in both cases the same, as a matter of fact this functionality already works, I just want to know is there are some sort of convention regarding this specific matter.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for either 400 or 401.

401 might be misleading because access to your API was not unauthorized. (especially if your api also requires authentication)

on the other hand [400](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) might be best :

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error

Comment: It is fair to say that a mistyped 3rd party token is a client error, thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I would say it should be a 401 still. The workings of your backend should have no bearing on the application in the sense that its inner workings aren't important to the end user. The fact that your auth service is telling you it isn't valid should be enough for you to throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

On this:

> My point is that the access to the application backend is authorized
>   and the parameters are correct (a token is present in the request), so
>   the response should be 200

The presence of a token does not mean that the request is valid. `401 Unauthorized` should be used, since invalid credentials were provided. From [httpstatuses.com](https://httpstatuses.com/401):

> The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication
>   credentials for the target resource.

If you were thinking it should be a 200 because the credential is not for your service, but for a third-party service and so authorization to your service is not failing, that could be argued, but in that case you still probably don't want to return a `200` but instead a `400 Bad Request` since the parameters to successfully complete the API operation are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'll buck the trend a bit and say you should return 200.

The status code 401 is related to HTTP authentication. W3C has the following to say on the status code:

> The request requires user authentication. **The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource.** The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
>   relevant diagnostic information.

([source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

Since your server presumably does not use HTTP authentication itself, you won't be returning a WWW-Authenticate header with a challenge, hence you won't be following this spec correctly. The 3rd party API you are calling may do this correctly, but that is by the by. Your user has requested a page from you, not the third party API directly, and they *are* authorised to do that. Your server has *not* decided that they are not worthy of a valid response - someone else's server has just told you that their token is not valid.

Given this, I would return a 200. The request *has* succeeded. Your server is able to return information indicating that the third party API call failed.

Comment: What you've explained is precisely my point but as you can see people have different opinion about this matter. Thank you for your answer !